# Hankel Transform with Bessel function of the first kind

Tags: physics, bessel-functions

I am trying to understand a substitution in a paper I am reading. The paper is "The Application of Linear Filter Theory to the Direct Interpretation of Geoelectrical Resistivity Sounding Measurements" by D.P. Ghosh. I am getting caught up on understanding how eqns 4 - 9 are derived. The equations are as follows:

$$ \rho_a(s) = s^2 \int_{0}^\infty T(\lambda) J_1(\lambda s)ds \qquad (4)$$
Where $\rho_a$ is the apparent resistivity and $T(\lambda)$ is a resistivity transform function. Using a Hankel Transform, we get:
$$ T(\lambda) = \int_{0}^\infty \rho_a(s) J_1(\lambda s)\left[\frac1s\right]ds \qquad (7)$$
New variables are then defined by
$$x = ln(s) \quad and \quad y = ln\left(\frac1\lambda\right) \qquad (8)$$
Substituting (8) in (7), we get
$$ T(y) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \rho_a(x) J_1\left( \frac{1}{e^{y-x}} \right)dx \qquad (9)$$
Please note that any missing equations were for another resistivity equation.

I can't figure out how the substitutions in (8) eliminated the $\frac1s$ in (7) and I'm not sure why the limit changes from 0 to $-\infty$. Any help in figuring this out would be great, I'm kind of stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have copied formula (4) incorrectly from the paper: $d\lambda$ not $ds$ in (4).

Starting with

$$T(\lambda) = \int_{s=0}^{s=\infty} \rho_a(s) J_1(\lambda s)\left[\frac1s\right]ds \qquad (7)$$

and using

$$x=\ln(s) \quad \Rightarrow \quad e^x = s \quad \mbox{and} \quad dx = \dfrac{1}{s}ds$$
$$\ln(0) \rightarrow -\infty \quad \mbox{and} \quad \ln(\infty) \rightarrow \infty$$

you now have

$$T(\lambda) = \int_{x=-\infty}^{x=\infty} \rho_a(x) J_1(\lambda e^x)dx$$

Then using

$$y = \ln\left(\dfrac{1}{\lambda}\right) \quad \Rightarrow \quad e^y = \dfrac{1}{\lambda}\quad \Rightarrow \quad {\lambda} = \dfrac{1}{e^y}$$

you now have

$$\begin{align} \\
T(y) &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \rho_a(x) J_1\left(\dfrac{1}{e^y} e^x\right)dx\\
\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \rho_a(x) J_1\left(\dfrac{1}{e^{y-x}}\right)dx \quad (9)\\
\end{align}$$

Comment: @Brian_Borchers thanks for the clarifying edit!

Comment: Note that the original author abused notation by equating $\rho_{a}(x)$ and $\rho_{a}(s)$.  If $\rho_{a}$ is treated as a fixed function, then you should have $\rho_{a}(e^{x})$ in (9).  Since $\rho_{a}$ is the apparent resitivity, it should only be evaluated at values from a depth of 0 to infinity.

Comment: @Brian_Borchers, yes I kept the same abuse of notation, which I took as an implicit redefinition of $\rho_a$.  R-dubs you need to be careful when following the paper.

Comment: Thank you so much! It was definitely an oversight of mine on equation 4, I'll be more careful in the future.